# Using MSSQL and MySQL database both as entity framework 6 model

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to work with MySQL with asp.net and I'm trying to use asp.net mvc 4 and entity framework 6 to view datas from MySQL & MSSQL database both. So far MSSQL is working fine. But whenever I try to view datas from MySQL tables I get this error,

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: Models.MySqlModel.ssdl(2,2) : error
0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered
in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

I've installed **MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.4** & **MySQL Connector .NET 6.8.3**, I've added `MySql.Data`, `MySql.Data.Entity.EF5`, `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` assemblies in the reference folder. This is my **Web.Config** code for db connection,

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ABCoLtd-20150101142609;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ABCoLtd-20150101142609.mdf" />
<add name="mytestdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SampleModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SampleModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SampleModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DREAGLEASUS64\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mytestdb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="mdsdata_demoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MySqlModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MySqlModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MySqlModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=4de570;database=mdsdata_demo&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

**Code from Controller to view data from MySQL table,**

```
namespace ABCoLtd.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        mytestdbEntities db = new mytestdbEntities();  //MSSQL Model
        mdsdata_demoEntities dsedb = new mdsdata_demoEntities();  //MySQL Model
        public ActionResult InstrumentList()
        {
           return View(dsedb.mkistats.ToList()); //The Line showing error
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I need this help badly. Please help me, your help will be really appreciated. Tnx.

**UPDATE**

When I see them in `Reference Manager` it says `6.8.3.0` but in `Properties` I get `6.8.4.0`. Is it the possible bug? If it is, what is the solution? See the images below,
[image: 6.8.3.0]
[image: 6.8.4.0]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you installed correct bit version and enable 32-bit applications in IIS.

And try to delete one of either references

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit. So still should I check it? And if so, can you just point me out where to look for enabling in IIS?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults

I say from my experience with Oracle providers. I had similar problem and there were 2 reasons for that: 32-bit apps should've been enabled, and data provider should've been registered in web.config/machine.config

There are both 32 and 64 bit versions of oracle data provider, I'm not sure about MySQL, so I suggested you to check this

Comment: I've followed the link given in the error & I added this line in the `<providers>` section of web.config, `<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />`.

Comment: Now I get this error, `[InvalidCastException: [A]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cannot be cast to [B]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection. Type A originates from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_6.8.3.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll'. Type B originates from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\Shihan Khan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2fa42747\4f539dcb\.....`

Comment: Check your Machine.config, maybe different version of this provider was registered there already

Comment: Which section of Machine.config should I need to check?

Comment: Version looks same, 6.8.3.0

Comment: BTW, why do you reference both MySql.Data.Entity.EF5 and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 ? I think it shouldn't be so...

Comment: Please see my updated question. Is this the real problem causing?

Comment: Yes, your last error happens because of this version difference.

Comment: Ok, how do I fix this? I've downloaded Connector 6.8.3.0 version. What should I do now?

Comment: Try to remove reference to EF5, if it doesn't help, try to add it back and remove EF6. If it still doesn't help, try the latest version of connector http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloadsandmirrorsites

Comment: Hi, tnx for sticking with me this long. I managed to install 6.8.3.0 but now I get this error, `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[ABCoLtd.Models.mkistat]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[ABCoLtd.Models.mdsdata_demoEntities]'.` Can u tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there's no error in code? It looks like type mismatch. It expects a collection of mdsdata_demoEntities but receives collection of mkistat, which is not related to the problem of your post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured the last error. TnQ so much for sticking with me.

Comment: Ok, have you solved the issue? If so, what was the problem, and were my suggestions helpful?

Comment: Yes, u r right about the version difference. I downloaded 6.8.3 directly from Package Manager. & the last error was my own mistake. I solved it. TnQ.